# Powershell - Capture text in a var from a specific character

Tags: powershell

I want to grab the first char of a var string and the first char of the following caracter

Example:

```
$var1 = "Jean-Martin"
```

I want a way to grab the first letter "J" then I want to take the first char following the "-" (dash) which is "M".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$var1 = "Jean-Martin"
```

To get the first character:

```
$var1[0]
```

To get the first character after the dash:

```
$characterToSeek = '-'
$var1[$var1.IndexOf($characterToSeek)+1]
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
$initial1 = $var1[0]
$initial2 = $var1.Split('-')[1][0]
```

Strings in Powershell use the System.String class from the .Net framework. As such, they are indexable to retrieve individual characters and have many methods available such as the Split method used above.

See the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.string.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Another option using regex:

```
PS> $var1 -replace '^(.)[^-]+-(.).+$','$1$2'
JM
```

Comment: wow that's advanced, I don't even understand what you are doing. But thanks for the help on that

Comment: Agree, it's a bit cryptic. The pattern remembers the first char and the first char after the dash sign and replaces the whole string with those matches.